# android custom list view is refreshing after deleting first item from list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, liferay, liferay-6

[image: My output is coming like this]

I am developing an android application, in that i using displaying pull notifications. I am getting the list of notification from backend and displaying in the form of custom list view.The problem is i am providing a button to delete particular notification from list view when ever i tried to delete the notification at any index it is deleting but after scrolling the entire list view is getting refreshed. How can i handle this?

one more thing is i am not using **notifysetdatachange()** anywhere.

```
public class NotificationListViewHolder extends BaseListAdapter.ViewHolder {
    //timeStamp, userName;
    public final CircleImageView profilePicture;
    public final TextView timeStamp;
    public final ImageView deleteNotification;
    public final ProgressBar progressBar;
    public final RelativeLayout notificationListItem;
    public TextView requirement;
    public LinearLayout clickableArea;
    NotificationListViewHolder viewHolder;
    NotificationListAdapter listAdapter;


    public NotificationListViewHolder(View view, BaseListAdapterListener listener, NotificationListAdapter listAdapter) {
        super(view, listener);
        requirement = view.findViewById(R.id.requirement);
        profilePicture = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
        notificationListItem = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_list_item);
        deleteNotification = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_notification);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        clickableArea = view.findViewById(R.id.clickable_area);
        timeStamp = view.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp);
        this.listAdapter = listAdapter;

    }

    public void bind(final Notification entry, NotificationListViewHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (holder.notificationListItem.getTag() == null) {
                holder.notificationListItem.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (NotificationListViewHolder) holder.notificationListItem.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(entry.isSelected()
                    ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(entry.isSelected()
                    ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);


            viewHolder.requirement.setText(entry.getRequirement());
            if (entry.getRoleName().equals("")) {
                viewHolder.timeStamp.setText(TimeFormat.getTimeStamp(entry.getTimestamp(), TimeFormatTypes.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION) + "");
            } else {
                viewHolder.timeStamp.setText(entry.getRoleName() + " - " + TimeFormat.getTimeStamp(entry.getTimestamp(), TimeFormatTypes.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION) + "");
            }
            if (viewHolder.profilePicture != null && !entry.getProfileUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Picasso.with(D4E.getContext()).load(D4E.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.liferay_server) + entry.getProfileUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_pic)
                        .error(R.drawable.default_profile_pic).into(viewHolder.profilePicture);
            }

            if (entry.getType() == 1) { // light grey , my post notifications || other post notification
                viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8FAD2"));
                viewHolder.requirement.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#030303"));
            } else if (entry.getType() == 2) {
                // the posts by others
            /*    viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDCDC"));
                viewHolder.requirement.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#030303"));*/
            } else if (entry.getType() == 0) { // dark grey , admin
                viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAC8"));
                viewHolder.requirement.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#030303"));
            }


            viewHolder.clickableArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    entry.setSelected(true);
                    deleteNotification();
                    viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                private void deleteNotification() {
                    Session session = SessionContext.createSessionFromCurrentSession();
                    session.setCallback(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void inBackground(Response response) {
                            ((Activity) D4E.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        AnimatorUtil.animate(viewHolder/*, true*/);
                                        listAdapter.getEntries().remove(listAdapter.getEntries().get(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()));
                                        listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
                                        UserInfoController.initializeUserInfoController().getUserInfo().setNotificationCount(listAdapter.getEntries().size());

                                       /* listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        listAdapter.getEntries().remove(listAdapter.getEntries().get(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()));
                                        listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
                                        listAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(), listAdapter.getEntries().size());
                                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        UserInfoController.initializeUserInfoController().getUserInfo().setNotificationCount(listAdapter.getEntries().size());*/
                                        /*if (listAdapter.getEntries().size() == 0)
                                            (() D4E.getContext()).onNoListItem();*/

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("Ex:Noti_List_Adp", "" + e.toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void doFailure(Exception exception) {
                            viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            entry.setSelected(false);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        new DeccategoryService(session).DeleteNotification(Long.parseLong(entry.getNotificationId()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

          /*  if (holder.notificationListItem.getTag() == null) {
                holder.notificationListItem.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (NotificationListViewHolder) holder.notificationListItem.getTag();
            }*/

           /* viewHolder.clickableArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    entry.setSelected(true);
                    // adapter.removeItem(entry,getAdapterPosition());
                    openDeleteNotification();
                    viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                private void openDeleteNotification() {
                    Session session = SessionContext.createSessionFromCurrentSession();
                    session.setCallback(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void inBackground(Response response) {
                            ((Activity) D4E.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    adapter.removeItem(entry, getAdapterPosition());

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void doFailure(Exception exception) {
                            viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            entry.setSelected(false);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        new DeccategoryService(session).DeleteNotification(Long.parseLong(entry.getNotificationId()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });*/

            viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(entry.isSelected()
                    ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            viewHolder.deleteNotification.setVisibility(entry.isSelected()
                    ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);


            viewHolder.requirement.setText(entry.getRequirement());
            if (entry.getRoleName().equals("")) {
                viewHolder.timeStamp.setText(TimeFormat.getTimeStamp(entry.getTimestamp(), TimeFormatTypes.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION) + "");
            } else {
                viewHolder.timeStamp.setText(entry.getRoleName() + " - " + TimeFormat.getTimeStamp(entry.getTimestamp(), TimeFormatTypes.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION) + "");
            }
            if (viewHolder.profilePicture != null && !entry.getProfileUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Picasso.with(D4E.getContext()).load(D4E.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.liferay_server) + entry.getProfileUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_pic)
                        .error(R.drawable.default_profile_pic).into(viewHolder.profilePicture);
            }

            if (entry.getType() == 1) {
                viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2F2F2"));
                viewHolder.requirement.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#030303"));
            } else if (entry.getType() == 2) {
/*                viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDCDC"));
                viewHolder.requirement.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#030303"));*/
            } else {
                viewHolder.notificationListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));//admin post color
            }


            //    FontStyle.getInstance().FontStyleByGroupOfIds(view.getContext(), new int[]{R.id.notification_list_item}, view);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }

    }


    public void createDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(D4E.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Alert!");
        builder.setMessage("Message from Admin");
        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

}
public class Notifications extends Scheduler implements ScreenletListListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, NoListListener, UpdateLogout {
public static boolean isInSettingsPage;
public static long notificationId;
public static String notificationSearchKeyword = "";
public static boolean notificationSearchActivated = false;
public static boolean navigatedFromPush = false;
ArrayList<digital.engineers.club.models.Notifications> notificationsModel;
BottomSheetDialog dialog;
View dialogView;
Menu menu;
GenericScreenlet screenlet;
SearchView searchView;
MenuItem searchMenuItem;
LinearLayout container;
View screenletView, noIntimationView;
private boolean shudRefreshOnResume = false;
//Push test

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);
    setContext(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    container = findViewById(R.id.ns);
    D4E.setContext(this);

    FontStyle.getInstance().setContext(this);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(FontStyle.getInstance()
            .getSpannableString(getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString()));

    container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    noIntimationView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.no_list_intimation, null);
    refreshNotifications();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;

    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nsettings);
    BitmapDrawable icon = (BitmapDrawable) menuItem.getIcon();
    Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (isInSettingsPage) {
            resetNotificationPage();
            isInSettingsPage = false;
        } else {
            if (navigatedFromPush) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class));
                navigatedFromPush = false;
            } else
                finish();
        }
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search) {
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nsettings) {
        isInSettingsPage = true;
        loadSettings();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void loadSettings() {
    FontStyle.getInstance().setContext(this);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(FontStyle.getInstance().getSpannableString("Notification Settings"));
    container.removeAllViews();
    if (searchMenuItem.isActionViewExpanded())
        searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new NotificationSettingsFragment()).commit();
}

private void openbootomsheet() {
    dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Notifications.this);
    dialogView = View.inflate(Notifications.this, R.layout.search_posts, null);
    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.search_by_time_layout);
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    ((Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.posted_time)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Notifications.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.day_search)));
    ((Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.role)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roles)));
    dialog.show();
    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.close_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.search_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onListPageReceived(int startRow, int endRow, List<Object> entries, int rowCount) {
    //  Toast.makeText(this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //UserInfoController.initializeUserInfoController().getUserInfo().setNotificationCount(0);
    UserInfoController.initializeUserInfoController().getUserInfo().setNotificationCount(entries.size());
    if (entries.size() == 0) {
        showNoNotificationIntimation();
    }

    /*screenlet.setVisibility(entries.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.no_list_layout)).setVisibility(entries.size() > 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);*/

}

@Override
public void onListItemSelected(Object element, View view) {
    Notification notification = (Notification) element;
    if (notification != null) {
        if (((Notification) element).getType() != 0) {
            notificationId = Long.parseLong(notification.getNotificationId());
            NewPost.postType = (SessionContext.getUserId() == Long.parseLong(notification.getPostedUserId())) ?
                    getResources().getString(R.string.post_type_my_post) :
                    getResources().getString(R.string.post_type_relevant_post);

            Map<String, Object> postMap = new HashMap<>();

            postMap.put("threadId", notification.getThreadId());
            postMap.put("profileUrl", SessionContext.getUserId() == Long.parseLong(notification.getPostedUserId()) ?
                    UserInfoController.initializeUserInfoController().getUserInfo().getProfileUrl() :
                    notification.getProfileUrl());
            postMap.put("firstName", notification.getFirstName());
            postMap.put("lastName", notification.getLastName());
            postMap.put("categoryId", notification.getCategoryId());
            postMap.put("timestamp", notification.getTimestamp());
            postMap.put("subject", notification.getSubject());
            postMap.put("threadStatus", notification.getThreadStatus());
            postMap.put("userId", String.valueOf(SessionContext.getUserId()));
            postMap.put("postedUserId", notification.getPostedUserId());
            postMap.put("userName", notification.getUserName());
            postMap.put("roleName", notification.getRoleName());


            // postMap.put("attachment",notification.getAttachment());

            ViewThread.post = new Post(postMap);
            ViewThread.post.setAttachment(notification.getAttachment());
            NewPost.currentPostId = ViewThread.post.getThreadId();
            NewPost.currentPosition = (SessionContext.getUserId() == Long.parseLong(notification.getPostedUserId())) ?
                    0 : 1; // View Pager position
            NewPost.postedUserId = Long.parseLong(ViewThread.post.getPostedUserId());
            HomeScreen.categoryId = Long.parseLong(ViewThread.post.getCategoryId());

            Intent intent = new Intent(Notifications.this, ViewThread.class);
            intent.putExtra("THREAD", ViewThread.post);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            createDialog(notification.getRequirement());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void error(Exception e, String userAction) {
    //  Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onListPageFailed(int startRow, Exception e) {
    //   Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void interactorCalled() {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (isScreenOn(this) && hasTimedOut) {
        initializeTimer();
        resetTimeOut();
        startSessionTimeCountDown();
    }


    if (shudRefreshOnResume) {
        if (!isInSettingsPage) {
            refreshNotifications();
            shudRefreshOnResume = false;
        } else {
            loadSettings();
        }
    }


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    shudRefreshOnResume = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (newText.length() > 3) {
        notificationSearchKeyword = newText;
        notificationSearchActivated = true;
        refreshNotifications();
    } else if (newText.length() == 0) {
        notificationSearchKeyword = "";
        notificationSearchActivated = false;
        refreshNotifications();
    }
    return true;
}

public void refreshNotifications() {
    container.removeAllViews();
    View notificationScreenlet = View.inflate(this, R.layout.notification_list_screenlet, null);
    screenlet = notificationScreenlet.findViewById(R.id.notification_list_screenlet);
    screenlet.setPagination();
    screenlet.setListener(this);
    container.addView(notificationScreenlet);
}

public void resetNotificationPage() {
    FontStyle.getInstance().setContext(this);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(FontStyle.getInstance().getSpannableString("Notifications"));
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
    refreshNotifications();
    notificationSearchActivated = false;
}


private void setItemsVisibility(Menu menu, MenuItem exception, boolean visible) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception) item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    notificationSearchActivated = false;
    if (isInSettingsPage) {
        resetNotificationPage();
        isInSettingsPage = false;
    } else {
        if (navigatedFromPush) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class));
            navigatedFromPush = false;
        } else
            finish();
    }

}

public void createDialog(String message) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(D4E.getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Message from Admin");
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void showNoNotificationIntimation() {
    container.removeAllViews();
    noIntimationView.findViewById(R.id.no_list_layout).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    container.addView(noIntimationView);
}

@Override
public void onNoListItem() {
    showNoNotificationIntimation();
}

@Override
public void onUpdatedLogoutToServer() {
    //if (SessionHelper.initializeSessionHelper().logout()) {
    DisplayDialog.display(this);
    /*} else {
        Log.e("LogoutErr", "Homescreen: Unable to Logout");
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to logout from scheduler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: any reasons for tagging this liferay-6 *and* liferay-7?

Comment: i am using list screentlet for displaying list of notifications

Comment: in both versions?

Comment: no only liferay 6 i am using

Answer (score 0):

when you delete item form list that time remove that item form list and notify adapter.
like below code ... when i am delete any item form recycler view ..

```
     yourlist.remove(yourlist.get(yourlist.indexOf(data))); // common data that pass in list.if List<String> that pass string data if object them pass that object data.
                            youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: this thing i am already using in my code  listAdapter.getEntries().remove(listAdapter.getEntries().get(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()));

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you should not use this method with viewholder. you should use getAdapterposition() to get position of row.

> [getLayoutPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition()) added in version 22.1.0
>
> int getLayoutPosition ()
>
> Returns the position of the ViewHolder in terms of the latest layout
>   pass.
>
> This position is mostly used by RecyclerView components to be
>   consistent while RecyclerView lazily processes adapter updates.
>
> For performance and animation reasons, RecyclerView batches all
>   adapter updates until the next layout pass. This may cause mismatches
>   between the Adapter position of the item and the position it had in
>   the latest layout calculations.
>
> LayoutManagers should always call this method while doing calculations
>   based on item positions. All methods in RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
>   RecyclerView.State, RecyclerView.Recycler that receive a position
>   expect it to be the layout position of the item.
>
> If LayoutManager needs to call an external method that requires the
>   adapter position of the item, it can use getAdapterPosition() or
>   convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout(int).

In your use case, since your data is related to your adapter contents (and I assume that data is changed at the same time with adapter changes), you should be using [adapterPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()).

Replace this lines

```
listAdapter.getEntries().remove(listAdapter.getEntries().get(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()));
listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
```

**with**

```
listAdapter.getEntries().remove(listAdapter.getEntries().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: Can you share output screen shot or gif ?